# Build Boost vs. include the headers

Tags: c++, boost

> Nothing to Build?
>
> Most Boost libraries are header-only: they consist entirely of header
>   files containing templates and inline functions, and require no
>   separately-compiled library binaries or special treatment when
>   linking.

I saw many people asking how to build Boost for Microsoft Visual C++, MinGW, and GCC...But Boost says they provide header-only libraries. Why not simply include these headers in the project, like using static libraries. Does the pre-building of Boost work only for saving the compilation time of the project?

Comment: __Most__ Boost libraries are header-only. __Most__ != __all__.

Comment: How would you pre-build a header-only library?

Comment: @tkausl OK...BTW any other advantage/difference?

Comment: No, the only reason is that you _must_ compile the libraries which are not header-only to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which library you wish to use. Almost all Boost libraries are header-only.

However, for example, Boost MPI needs to be compiled.

It is not a question of saving compilation time. There is no such thing as prebuilding header only library. (I am sure somebody will comment about precompiled headers, but it is another subject and is not recommended while using Boost.)